# Unresolved class 'MainActivity' in Androidmanifest. How do I fix it?

Tags: flutter

This question has been asked many times but not recently.  I have looked into the old methods and they do not seem to be relevant today.

My AndroidManifest has many errors, one of them being MainActivity is unresolved.  Please help me troubleshoot this.  I am using a picture of my AndroidManifest to show where the errors are in red writing.

[image: Picture of AndroidManifest]

Here is my MainActivity.kt file:

```
package com.henrohelper100.app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Here is my Gradle file:

```
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
namespace "com.henrohelper100.app"
compileSdkVersion 33
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.henrohelper100.app"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: 
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 5
    versionName '1.0.5'
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? 
file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

}

flutter {``
source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is incorrect. Try using a program like sublime and select the syntax so that its the same as the language you are coding in so it automatically formats the code correctly.

```
<application
    android:label="Henro Helper"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"         
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard|">

    </activity>

</application>
```

Also make sure that android:name inside the application tag is set to the correct package name used in your xml file. So change android:name to `android:name="com.henrohelper100.app.MyApplication"`

Comment: Do you mean the name of my app Henro Helper? Or do you mean com.henrohelper100.app  Would I put a period in front of that?  There is a period in front of .MyApplication

Comment: Check the name of the package attribute within the manifest tag in AndroidManifest.xml file is identical to package name used inside your MainActivity.kt file. So android:name="com.henrohelper100.app.MyApplication" in xml and <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.henrohelper100.app"> inside .kt file.

Comment: Your MainActivity.kt file should also have 'package com.henrohelper100.app'

Comment: I refer to two seperate files: AndroidManifest.xml which has <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.henrohelper100.app"> and  MainActivity.kt which has the package declaration at the top of the file like 'package com.henrohelper100.app'

Comment: OK, I have made sure everything is there and I did a flutter clean and pub get.  However, there is still an error for  android:name="com.henrohelper100.app.MyApplication"

Comment: The image you sent of the xml file contains <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.henrohelper100.app"> at the beginning of the file. So Just edit this line to reflect the packname being used in your MainActivity file

Comment: post the error details

Comment: Have you resynced your project with gradle and rebuilt the project? Run 'flutter doctor' to identify potential problems with your flutter SDK and dependencies

Comment: OK, I did not resync the project with gradle.  The information about how to resync the gradle file that I have found seems to be outdated.  Everyone just says " click on file and then click on resync with gradle" however, resync with gradle is not an option under file.  What I am saying is that the resync with gradle button does not exist.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio in Windows?

Comment: If your using Windows, you can run cmd and from your Android Studio Project root directory you can execute ./gradlew.bat clean followed by ./gradlew.bat build. This will sync your project

Comment: OK, I tried to sync in CMD.  Got the following error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\jdevo\HenroHelper\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
      Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151

Comment: You need to download Java11 from the Oracle website.

Comment: OK I will do that.  So many things they do not tell you about on Flutter tutorial videos.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should always check your packages and dependencies are up to date including your version of android studios

Comment: Remember to update the JAVA_HOME environment variable and system PATH once Java11 has finished installing and then run gradlew sync from your project root directory

Comment: If you are talking about the Gradle JDK, I have jbr-17 JeBrains 17.0.6   I installed android studio 6 months ago, I am not sure why my java would be so outdated.

Comment: type java --version to check which version of JAVA your using

Comment: OK, I got Java installed and updated JAVA_HOME.  I ran gradlew.bat clean and it works fine.  When I run gradlew.bat build I get stuck on > :app:compileFlutterBuildProfile.  Everything else says Idle, my progress stays at 16%.  Any idea on what is going on here?

Comment: I did open the android folder of my application in android studio.  I was able to use "sync project with gradle files" there.  The build was successful.  However, when I look at my flutter application my .MainActivity is still red with error Unresolved class 'MainActivity'  and my android:name="com.henrohelper100.app.MyApplication" is still red with error Unresolved class 'MyApplication'

Comment: use 'flutter clean' in your flutter project directory followed by 'flutter pub get' to check your dependencies Also use 'flutter upgrade' to make sure your version of flutter is the latest.

Comment: You said you opened your project folder inside android studio, but instead you may want to start a new project which involves configuring settings such as android version etc..

Comment: Also make sure to change your Java JDK in Android Studio by going to the "File" menu and selecting "Project Structure." then navigating to "Project" and select ing the JDK version Under the "Project SDK" dropdown menu.. 
In the "Project Structure" dialog, go to "SDK Location" in the left panel.
Set the "JDK location" to the path of your 'JDK' installation. Android Studio will now use the specified Java Development Kit 'JDK' version for your project. Thenrebuild your project after